# How can I develop this ML/AI system that I want to use in my new mobile app?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, image-processing

I have an idea for a new mobile app. Here is what I want to accomplish using AI;
I want to get an *image (png format)*, (*maybe just byte data too*), from my application (*I'm developing with Unity3D/C#*), send this data to AI application; get modified image from ML app and send it back to my app.

**What AI is going to do with img?**
Imagine you are the user of my app; you are going to draw a picture on your phone.
Picture will be simple, *like a seagull illustrated as an **'M'** letter*.
AI program will get your drawing (*'M' in this case*), check pixels to give a meaning to *'M'*; then draw a more complex drawing that is themed around that *M seagull*.
*(Like a drawing with an ocean made by Pixel Art, with rain clouds from Van Gogh and **seagull** is painted as a surreal bird...)*

---

**My general idea about building this AI system...**
I'm not sure how to build this AI system, because I can't understand AI/ML completely. How it works on machine, how to implement it using computer, how to write an algorithm, how pre-made libraries like *Tensorflow* works... But I'm in a phase of my life that I need to use my time well, and want to build this app while learning.
I think, I can build an side app to use for *analyzing* and *modifying* image I get from user. Right know I can write in C, C# and learning JavaScript. I learned Python too (and a few others), but I'm not comfortable using it. (*I hate Python*). And didn't write a good program in any other language...
I thought, I can use [JavaScript](https://www.tensorflow.org/js?hl=tr) or [Java || C++](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android?hl=tr) but *honestly* I don't know how to start and which steps to take. Also after gaining some success I *will* want to port app to **iOS** too... Maybe that can wait...

Can you give me some examples, guidelines and advices? *How to start doing this **while deciding; what is best approach, performance and development-time wise**?*
*And,* **Is my approach to the problem is a good one?** ***Can you come up with a better solution for my idea that you can tell me to point me in another direction?***

Comment: This is a very ambitious fist project, although you may find some pre-made neural networks that your could just wire up. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5U4NgVGAwg or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iM4PPGDQry0

Comment: If you want to understand the AI/ML behind this, you should put the project to one side for a while and study the basics. It won't be possible to build your app and just add this type of component as you go along.

Comment: Okay, "study the basics". I need to learn, practice, understand. I need to learn in my way, if I must say, I'm a little different on learning subject. What is the best way for this? Any resources you like, which steps to take, which subjects to look at? Also, academic side of AI/ML research is a little heavy for a solo person to learn. But I really want to learn this thing from ground up! Also I think I understand theoric side, I don't understand techical side, yet. @NeilSlater

Comment: @NeilSlater Also thanks for links! I am checking them out.

Comment: @NeilSlater I recently had some friends design some website for face recognition with no ML knowledge but just by using a Face recognition API. Apparently such high level apis actually exist, the OP is probably talking about Neural Style Transfer (which is popular IMO) so it might exist.

Comment: @DuttaA I think my idea contains both Image Generation and Neural Style Transfer techniques. Do you know such a API?

Comment: No. but I think you can  pick any piece of readymade code from GitHub (giving due credits of course) and just run it on back end.